# My page moves/repositions in the browser! (but looks ok in the Coda preview)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding. 
My code looks like it should in the Coda Preview, but when I open it in the browser (Chrome) everything has moved. It moves as a change the brwoser window. I would like it to look the same at all times. What did I do wrong?

(Also, I can't get my slideshow in the background to work. Do you know why?)

Would really appreciate some help!

Here is the Jsfiddle and my CSS: 
[My website](https://jsfiddle.net/56qLdxfa/2/)

```css
/* StyleSheet */

body {
  background-image: "sushi_main.jpg";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#overlay{
  position: center;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  width: 59%;
  height: 100%;
  size: 80px 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 820px;
  padding: 60px;
  
}

#header{
  position: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #030303;
  opacity: 100;
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 125px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 730px;
  left: 15.5%;
  top: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: right;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}
#logo {
  position:auto;
  margin-left:68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 500;
  width:80px;
  height:130px;
  padding: 30;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
  max-height: 25px;
  width: 731px;
  left: 165px;
  top: 118px;
  word-spacing: 90px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
p1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #030303;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
p2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-style: bottom;
  border-width: 5px;
}

p3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
p4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-style: bottom;
  border-width: 5px;
  columns: 2;
  column-width: 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
a:hover{
  color:#e5001a; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  cursor:pointer;  
}
.active {
  background-color: #9e520f;
}
a {
  color: #030303;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
#footer  {
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: #030303;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
hr { 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#colum  {
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: rgba 0, 0, 0, 0.65;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  column-count: 2;
}
html { 
  min-height: 100%; 
}
body { 
  height: 100%; 
}
.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideshow li span{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}
.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url(sushi_main.jpg); 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(sushii.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span{
  background-image: url(akiko_sushi.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span     {
  background-image: url(pabu_sushi.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:960px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<title>Sushi website Midterm</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sushi.css">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
    <p1>TJOHLANGAJEBFKSCB LHE VSCBFF</p1>
  </div>

  <body background="sushi_main.jpg">


    <div id="header">

      <img id="logo" src="ss_logo2-01.png" alt="Sushi in San Francisco Logo" style="float:left;" />

      <h1>Sushi in San Francisco</h1>

    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <p1>

        <ul>
          <a href="movies.html">AKIKO's</a></li>
        <a href="dogs.html">Sushi1</a></li>
      <a href="food.html">Sushi2</a></li>
    <a href="index.html">Sushi3</a></li>
  </ul>


</p1>
</div>

<div id="overlay">

  <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>


  <center>
    <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
    </p2>
  </center>

  <hr>

  <h2>AKIKO's </h2>

  <div id="colum">
    <p4>Akiko's, at 431 Bush and not related to the restaurant of the same name on Mason Street, is a cult hit in the making because it has all the intriguing elements that provide cachet: There's no sign on or over the door, so it's easy to miss. If
      you call the restaurant you're likely to encounter a full voice-mail box; fortunately, you can book on OpenTable, or show up and hope for a table or a seat at the sushi bar. The restaurant has been around for 18 years, but, four years ago, Ray
      Lee bought out his parents and brought in Ricky Yap as chef. In the last few months, they've ramped up the menu, hired more staff, remodeled and expanded the sushi bar and took out some tables. All told, the restaurant seats 38. Once inside,
      diners are greeted by a friendly host, but if you have a reservation after 7 or so you may still have to wait a half hour for a table. People don't seem to be in a rush to leave.
    </p4>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

  <center>
    <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
    </p2>
  </center>

  <hr>

  <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

  <center>
    <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
    </p2>
  </center>

  <hr>

  <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

  <center>
    <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
    </p2>
  </center>

  <hr>

  <divone>
    <p3>Copyright my name 2016</p3>
  </divone>


  <ul class="slideshow">

    <li> <span>sushi_main.jpg</span> </li>

    <li> <span>Slide Two</span> </li>

    <li> <span>Slide Three</span> </li>

    <li> <span>Slide Four</span> </li>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML in your fiddle is completely ill-formed: no `<html>` tag, multiple `<body>`, unclosed tags, ...

You should read again [HTML basics](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp), and use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) before posting your code.

Here is a fixed version:

```css
/* StyleSheet */

body {
  background-image: "sushi_main.jpg";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#overlay{
  position: center;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  width: 59%;
  height: 100%;
  size: 80px 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 820px;
  padding: 60px;
  
}

#header{
  position: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #030303;
  opacity: 100;
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 125px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 730px;
  left: 15.5%;
  top: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: right;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}
#logo {
  position:auto;
  margin-left:68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 500;
  width:80px;
  height:130px;
  padding: 30;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
  max-height: 25px;
  width: 731px;
  left: 165px;
  top: 118px;
  word-spacing: 90px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
p1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #030303;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
p2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-style: bottom;
  border-width: 5px;
}

p3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
p4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f4f5f7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-style: bottom;
  border-width: 5px;
  columns: 2;
  column-width: 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
a:hover{
  color:#e5001a; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  cursor:pointer;  
}
.active {
  background-color: #9e520f;
}
a {
  color: #030303;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
#footer  {
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: #030303;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
hr { 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#colum  {
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: rgba 0, 0, 0, 0.65;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  column-count: 2;
}
html { 
  min-height: 100%; 
}
body { 
  height: 100%; 
}
.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideshow li span{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}
.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url(sushi_main.jpg); 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(sushii.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span{
  background-image: url(akiko_sushi.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span     {
  background-image: url(pabu_sushi.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:960px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Sushi website Midterm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sushi.css">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="navbar">
      <p1>TJOHLANGAJEBFKSCB LHE VSCBFF</p1>
    </div>

    <div background="sushi_main.jpg">


      <div id="header">

        <img id="logo" src="ss_logo2-01.png" alt="Sushi in San Francisco Logo" style="float:left;" />

        <h1>Sushi in San Francisco</h1>

      </div>

      <div id="navbar">
        <p1>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="movies.html">AKIKO's</a></li>
            <li><a href="dogs.html">Sushi1</a></li>
            <li><a href="food.html">Sushi2</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Sushi3</a></li>
          </ul>


        </p1>
      </div>

      <div id="overlay">

        <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>


        <center>
          <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
          </p2>
        </center>

        <hr>

        <h2>AKIKO's </h2>

        <div id="colum">
          <p4>Akiko's, at 431 Bush and not related to the restaurant of the same name on Mason Street, is a cult hit in the making because it has all the intriguing elements that provide cachet: There's no sign on or over the door, so it's easy to miss. If
            you call the restaurant you're likely to encounter a full voice-mail box; fortunately, you can book on OpenTable, or show up and hope for a table or a seat at the sushi bar. The restaurant has been around for 18 years, but, four years ago, Ray
            Lee bought out his parents and brought in Ricky Yap as chef. In the last few months, they've ramped up the menu, hired more staff, remodeled and expanded the sushi bar and took out some tables. All told, the restaurant seats 38. Once inside,
            diners are greeted by a friendly host, but if you have a reservation after 7 or so you may still have to wait a half hour for a table. People don't seem to be in a rush to leave.
          </p4>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

        <center>
          <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
          </p2>
        </center>

        <hr>

        <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

        <center>
          <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
          </p2>
        </center>

        <hr>

        <h2>Experience Exceptional </h2>

        <center>
          <p2>There are four sushi restaurants in San Francisco you do not want to miss. On this site we'll help you find these treasures in the city jungle and experience some exceptional culinary skills. Click the menu to get started or simply scroll down.
          </p2>
        </center>

        <hr>

        <divone>
          <p3>Copyright my name 2016</p3>
        </divone>


        <ul class="slideshow">

          <li> <span>sushi_main.jpg</span> </li>

          <li> <span>Slide Two</span> </li>

          <li> <span>Slide Three</span> </li>

          <li> <span>Slide Four</span> </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```